# Can't execute powershell script from salt-master on windows minion(2008r2):

Tags: powershell, salt-stack

I tried to execute powershell script from salt-master to my windows minion(win2008r2), the result shows True and Succeeded: 1 (changed=1), note.ps1 contain "Start-Process "C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe"

```
# cat note.sls
win_script:
 cmd.run:
  - name: powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\note.ps1

# salt 'win2008r2' state.sls note
win2008r2:
----------
      ID: win_script
Function: cmd.run
    Name: powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\note.ps1
  Result: True
 Comment: Command "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\note.ps1" run
 Started: 22:30:55.178000
Duration: 4774.0 ms
 Changes:
          ----------
          pid:
              2844
          retcode:
              0
          stderr:
          stdout:

Summary for win2008r2
------------
Succeeded: 1 (changed=1)
Failed:    0
------------
Total states run:     1
Total run time:   4.774 s
```

and

```
# cat note.sls
win_script:
 cmd.run:
  - name: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\note.ps1


# salt 'win2008r2' state.sls note
win2008r2:
----------
      ID: win_script
Function: cmd.run
    Name: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\note.ps1
  Result: True
 Comment: Command "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\note.ps1" run
 Started: 22:43:27.207000
Duration: 250.0 ms
 Changes:
          ----------
          pid:
              2308
          retcode:
              0
          stderr:
              File C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\note.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execu
              tion of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing"
               for more details.
                  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordE
                 xception
                  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
          stdout:

Summary for win2008r2
------------
Succeeded: 1 (changed=1)
Failed:    0
------------
Total states run:     1
Total run time: 250.000 ms
```

if i perform the above command manaully on the windows minion we can get the open notepad but unable to find the results by doing salt-master.

Comment: Are you expecting to open notepad via Salt?

Comment: "if i perform the above command manually on the windows minion we can get the open notepad but unable to find the results by doing from salt-master." - yes i expect the new notepad on the windows minion.